# Call OpenCL CPU Kernel via function pointer

Tags: opencl

I want to use OpenCL as a simple C runtime JIT on the CPU. Because the kernels are ASCII, i can modify them at runtime, and compile/execute the code. This part is straightforward enough.

However, I'd like to have function pointer access to the resulting compiled kernel, so that it can be called conventionally from C code, rather then having to access the kernel through openCL API.

Obviously this only works on the CPU where the memory is shared.

It seems this should be possible, any thoughts?

Comment: why not just write a small wrapper function which invokes the OpenCL kernel? you can then just pass around the pointer to the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't be done. You need to use clEnqueueTask. If you were somehow able to get the address of the CPU kernel and reverse engineer the parameters passed, it would be subject to change with a driver update.

If you need runtime compilation look at linking to LLVM or similar.